# How to set text color to Edit Contol in ATL Control?

Tags: atl, textcolor, editcontrol

I have a ATL ActiveX Control with Edit Control. I want to set text color to the control of as per specific conditions. 

I cannot use **setTextColor** as there is no MFC support to the the control.
I am also not able to use 'WM_CTLCOLOREDIT' message as I don't have access to CDC and CWnd.

I had similar issue setting text input limit but I accomplished it using SendMessage(EM_LIMITTEXT, (WPARAM)1000, (LPARAM)0);  but could not find any message for setting text color. 

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: First, you want to handle [`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761691.aspx) message. Second, what makes you believe you need `CDC` or `CWnd` to handle it?

Comment: Thanks Igor. I corrected the message name to WM_CTLCOLOREDIT in my question.<br>

Comment: WM_CTLCOLOREDIT handler function needed parameters HBRUSH CMyDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) so I though I would need CDC and CWnd.  I found another version of handling WM_CTLCOLOREDIT. LRESULT CMyDialog::OnCtlColorEdit(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled) But this message gets called while loading the dialog. Can I call it explicitly on click of a Check box to change the color of edit control text ?

Comment: `needed parameters HBRUSH` No it does not. From the documentation article I linked to: "If an application processes this message, it must **return** the handle of a brush". Emphasis mine. Why are you looking at MFC documentation at all, when you say you don't want to use MFC? `this message gets called while loading the dialog` This message is sent whenever the edit control needs to repaint itself, for whatever reason. You could call [`InvalidateRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx) to give it such a reason.

Comment: Igor, I am able to set the color now. The reason for the color not setting was that my edit control was set to readonly (which was the projects requirement). I have now set control to editable and ignoring user input's on the control using the OnChange event.

Comment: Read-only edit control sends `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message instead. You handle it the same way as `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`